# Can a substitution cause a convergent definite integral to diverge?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible for an integral, $$\int_a^b f(x)\text{d}x,$$ to converge, but for some substitution $x=g(y)$ to cause the integral, $$ \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(y)) g'(y) \text{d}{y},$$ to diverge?

I suppose this could happen if $$f(g(y))g'(y)\longrightarrow\infty$$ as $y\longrightarrow g^{-1}(a)$ or $y\longrightarrow g^{-1}(b)$ ? Or, equivalently, if $$f(a)g'(g^{-1}(a))=\infty$$ or $$f(b)g'(g^{-1}(b))=\infty.$$

**Edit**

I originally asked this question because certain substitutions appeared to make the integrand become "pathalogical" or to blow up to infinity at certain points, so from an "area under the curve" point of view I found it difficult to see how convergence could persist. However, indeed such functions can converge, e.g. $ x^{-1/2} $ over $[0,1] $

Comment: If the original integral is a standard Riemann integral and not improper, then $f$ is bounded. However, you can certainly make a substitution that sends a bounded interval to an unbounded one, e.g., substituting $x=1/y$ on $(0,1]$. But if your function $g$ is continuously differentiable (as most substitutions are in calculus) on the whole closed interval, you won't get an improper integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case of an non closed interval.

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{a'\downarrow a, b'\uparrow b} \int_{a'}^{b'}f(x)dx$$
ans the integrals
$$
\int_{a'}^{b'}f(x)dx
$$are definite Riemann integrals (so $f$ is bounded on $[a',b']$).

Now make the change in the definite integrals:
$$ \int_{a'}^{b'}f(x)dx
=   \int_{g^{-1}(a')}^{g^{-1}(b')} f(g(y)) g'(y) {d}{y}
$$
These integrals are well defined. Now the first integral si convergent iff
$$
\lim_{a'\downarrow a, b'\uparrow b} \int_{a'}^{b'}f(x)dx =
\lim_{a'\downarrow a, b'\uparrow b} 
 \int_{g^{-1}(a')}^{g^{-1}(b')} f(g(y)) g'(y) {d}{y}
$$ exists. As $g^{-1}$ is continuous when $g\in C^1$, the preceding expression becomes
(assuming $g$ increasing, otherwise just change the inequalities accordingly):

$$
\lim_{ga\downarrow g^{-1}(a), gb\uparrow g^{-1}(b)} 
 \int_{ga}^{gb} f(gy)) g'(y) {d}{y}
$$

which proves that one integral is convergent iff the other one is.